# How to know a pdb file is public or private?

Tags: windbg, pdb-files

When I load a pdb file with WinDbg, How to know that pdb file is public or private?

Comment: I'm confused by the 'export symbols' listed by the Windbg.                   eg: 0:124>lm                                                                               002a0000 002bd000   mdll_1 C (export symbols)       mdll_smibprotocol.dll
00020000 00034000   mdll_2 C (private pdb symbols)  d:\windbg\mypdb\mdll_2.pdb                                                                The second dll has private pdb but the first one mdll_1 really doesn't have a pdb by a compile mistake. So what's the export symbols? It misleads me in a crash dump as so far.

Answer (score 6):

View the module with lm, it will tell you if the associated PDB is private. For example, this PDB is public:

```
0: kd> lm mntdll
start             end                 module name
00007ffe`aee40000 00007ffe`af001000   ntdll      (pdb symbols)          c:\websymbols\ntdll.pdb\F296699DB5314A06935E88564D8CD2731\ntdll.pdb
```

And this one is private:

```
0: kd> lm mole32
Browse full module list
start             end                 module name
00007ffe`ac550000 00007ffe`ac693000   ole32      (private pdb symbols)  c:\websymbols\ole32.pdb\C8E3042BDD6A44BA8D9CCF8E433F33DF1\ole32.pdb
```

Comment: @Andy: perhaps you like `lm m ntdll` (with space). To me it makes it more clear what the options are and what the DLL name is